# Run a shell script on Ubuntu startup

Tags: shell, ubuntu, boot

I have a shell scrip that runs on jvm, it works as I write: `sh /opt/bin/myshel.sh` 
I added a shell script to /etc/inti.d with this detail:

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          WSO2Services.sh
# Required-Start:    $local_fs
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO

/opt/bin/myshel.sh
```

I saved this file as "myShell.sh" in "/etc/init.d" and change it's mode to executable. And also I used  `sudo update-rc.d myShell.sh defaults` to update the "rc*.d" files.
The problem is that it is not running on the reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to have something executed on boot is putting it in /etc/rc.local. If you want to write a full Sys V init script, you probably want to use on of the existing scripts as template. You might also want to consider using an upstart job.

Comment: I totally can not understand what you are saying i'm a real naive!

Comment: Add /opt/bin/myshel.sh to /etc/rc.local and see if it gets executed upon reboot.

Comment: You mean I change rc.local file to this:

`#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

/opt/bin/myshel.sh

exit 0
`

Comment: @RezaAmeri: Nope. Just add a line at the end of the rc.local script to call your scipt (`/opt/bin/myshell.sh`).

Comment: @TrueY you mean after exit 0? Or after comments and before exit 0? Or may be I have to remove exit 0 and add `/opt/bin/myshell.sh`?
 Thanks for help.

Comment: @RezaAmeri: I do not have the `exit 0`, but of course before it.

Answer (score 1):

At first check `/etc/inittab` file. There is a line like `id:2:initdefault` So it will start at runlevel `2` (in my case). So this will start at boot: `/etc/init.d/rc 2`. So all scripts starting S##somename (# is a decimal digit) in `/etc/rc2.d` will be run. These are symbolic links to the scripts in `/etc/init.d`.

So similar has to be done in your case. If your runlevel is `2` then create a symlink in /etc/rc2.d/S##myshell.sh to the script in `../init.d/myshel.sh`. Then it will run during boot. Keep in mind the scripts having the same script level (the two decimal digit after `S`) run parallel.

I would suggest you to check the files in /etc/init.d how they should look like, what arguments should be supported.

Comment: That's what `update-rc.d [name] defaults` does

Comment: @glennjackman: I did not know that. Thx!

Comment: My problem is exactly the skeleton of files in init.d I want to create a file in init.d that runs my shell and has the standard skeleton.